# Get only applications with launchers through adb

Tags: android, adb

I have to get the package name of all the applications installed on the phone which has a launcher i.e. which appears in the app list of the phone.

I know pm list packages lists down all the package but it also includes the services and system applications. I want only the apps which show up on the app menu of the phone.

Also I don't want to use monkey runner, any other alternative would be great.

Any help?

Comment: `pm list packages -3` gets all third party apps. It doesn't do what you want but I think that is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling getLaunchIntentForPackage() in PackageManager on each package installed.  If it returns null, then it has no launcher.  Although you may get a few false positives from apps with a MAIN activity but without a launcher.

Comment: Is there a way I can use this on adb? Not in the android code?